# Is skewness always bad?

Tags: distributions, skewness, nonparametric

In my experiment, I hypothesised that individuals in one treatment condition would give higher values on a likert scale than individuals in the other treatment condition. It was a one tailed hypothesis.

Histograms and Q plots show that my data is skewed in the direction I would imagine for the first treatment condition - i.e. all clustering around the higher values in the Likert scale. This isn't the case, again as expected, in the second treatment condition.

Even though I predicted this, is this skew still bad? Should I always use non-parametric tests in this situation (the results of parametric and nonparametric tests are the same - I just want to make sure I am using the right tests!).

Any help would be really gratefully received!

Thanks!

Comment: I would not think in terms of "good" or "bad" as this is not a statistical category. Skewness just is.

Comment: But I guess your question has a different background, so why do you think skewness is "bad"? Because it is a departure from symmetry? Please share more about the data (e.g., sample size and number of items in the scale) and what test you were thinking of.  you have

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site.

Skewness isn't "bad" (nor is it "good"). Skewness may be a violation of assumptions of a test, in which case either figure out a way to fix it, or use a different test.

If you are comparing two single item Likert scales, then all your values will be integers (say, from 1 to 5 or whatever), in which case the mean is going to be related to skewness: You can't have a high mean on a 5 point scale without having left skew.

It is also arguable that even taking the mean on a single item scale like this is unjustified: The scale is ordinal, not interval (actually, it's in-between).

I suggest a nonparametric test. Which one did you use?